# How to implement mvregress on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression

I am new to Matlab. I am trying to estimate the coefficients of my linear regression:

Ypca = A + B ∙ X + Epca

I have the table Ypca which is 15*3884 table and table X which is 7769*2 table.

I used the following code:

[beta,Sigma] = mvregress(X,Y,'algorithm','cwls');

My goal is to find out A, B and Epca.

But the error that I am getting is as follows:

[image]
Can someone please tell me how to proceed with this error? Thank you.

Trail is the name of my mat file.

Answer (score 2):

you have a single variable, so no need to use multi-variate regression, just call polyfit to do a linear fitting

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html

Comment: I am trying to implement a research paper, where the author mentioned she used mvregress to estimate the regression coefficients.